# Mac finder windows type is grayed out It's driving me crazy

Tags: macos, window, visibility, finder

When I go to save as a new file, all the files listed in the Finder window are grayed out (folder names display normally). I want the file names to be black too.

This may have happened because of a script I ran on my Mac years back. It may have been one that allowed to see a file kinda 'flying' when I dragged it from one finder window to another and it grayed out the list of Finder file names as the move was happening until the move was complete.

Anyway, after several OS upgrades, now the file names are permanently grayed out – but only when I try to save a file. [grayed out file names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyk2h.jpg)

Is there any way to get my file names back to display normally?

Comment: This is the normal behavior on macOS for years and years. I can't recall if or when it's been otherwise and I've been using Macs since 1987. It indicates that you can't "select" an existing file (although you can click on them to change the name field to contain the clicked-on file's name).

Comment: Oh really, hmmmm. In my case, the type is so light as to be ineligible. I guess I'm going to call on Apple for help. Thanks, Ken!